# Dagger+Robolectric+Gradle+APT - source not generated for test module

Tags: gradle, robolectric, apt, dagger

(Question is available as a github repo [here](https://github.com/jacobtabak/Robolectric-Dagger-Skeleton))

Edit: it looks like this is an issue with android-apt not playing nicely with robolectric.  'gradle clean assembleDebugTest' will generate the test sources, but 'gradle clean test' will not.  I think `android-apt` will need to be modified to work for this case.

Edit 2: I solved my problem by changing temporarily using `compile` rather than `apt`, `androidTestApt`, or `provided`.  This question will remain open though, because we shouldn't be including that stuff in our apks.

I currently have dependency in my project that requires the Android APT plugin.  Unfortunately, I can't get my test to pass when the APT plugin is applied.

Here's a brief overview of the project structure:

```
src
├───androidTest/java/com.example.myapplication
│   ├───MyTest
│   ├───TestModule
│   └───TestMyApplication [extends Application]
│
└───main/java/com.example.myapplication
    ├───MyApplication
    └───MyModule
```

TestMyApplication overrides the `getModules()` method in MyApplication and adds TestModule.

My dependencies section looks like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
  apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
  androidTestApt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
  androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
  androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3'
}
```

Yet still, I get an error at runtime:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class com.example.myapplication.TestModule could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.

If I disable the `android-apt` and use `provides` instead of `apt` and `androidTestApt`, everything works great!

Notably, `provides` does not work if the `android-apt` plugin is applied.

For the complete source, please check out my repo here to illustrate this issue:  https://github.com/jacobtabak/Robolectric-Dagger-Skeleton

There are 3 branches -

- `master`, which is my original case that I want to work
- `provided`, which works using `provided` and has the `android-apt` plugin disabled
- `aptfail`, which is the exact same case as above, except with the `android-apt` plugin applied, that fails.

Thanks! For an answer to be accepted it must NOT used 'compile' for the dagger compiler.

Comment: I don't think your Roboelectric tests are in the right place. Gradle `test` runs plain java unit tests, while `assembleDebugTest` packages Android instrumentation tests that run on a device. The `android-apt` plugin supports the latter. So even if you move the tests to the right place you'll run into the issue that `android-apt` does not hook into java test compiles, there's an open issue for that. When you say that `android-apt` breaks `provided`, that may be a bug. There's a lot written on Roboelectric and Android Gradle, so there might be more issues.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle - I'm pretty sure the tests are in the right place.  If apt-android cannot support this scenario that is understandable, but someone told me recently that 'apt' configuration is basically the same as the 'provided' configuration except 'apt' gives you the ability to configure the compiler arguments.  I believe there's a way to make this work - but it's certainly not your responsibility to find it.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'd like to make it work, but it would make more sense to me if unit tests are in the meant-to-be place for that. The deckard project you link to has the tests in `src/test/java` though, unlike what you describe here. I'll invest some time in it this week to see what I can do in `android-apt` to make it work.

Comment: Awesome, I did try changing the name of the test dir but it did not make a difference.  I appreciate your attention to it!  Ironically, my 'fix' of using compile rather than apt put me over the dex method limit.